# Why did the image sources in the array change?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of images, that I got from facebook. In a for loop I assign an element of the array to a new variable. I then change the variables source to a different one, but with it the source of the arrays element changes too.

```
function getImages(){
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('div.userContentWrapper img');
    return images;
}

function getImageHeight(image){
        return image.height;
}

function getImageWidth(image){
        return image.width;
}

function replaceImages(images) {
        var baseImageUrl, height, width, image;
                baseImageUrl = 'http://placekitten.com/g/';

        for (var i=0, len=images.length; i<len; i++){
                image = images[i];
                height = getImageHeight(image);
                width = getImageWidth(image);
                image.src = baseImageUrl + width + '/' + height;
        }
}
```

I don't understand why does the element `images[i]` change when we change `image.src`
If I had any say in this, I would have put `images[i].src = image.src;` at the end of the loop, but it seems like that isn't necessary.
Maybe someone can recommend what I should read up to understand this issue better.

Also, is it necessary/advisable to create so many small functions?

This is my first question here, so I apologize, if I wasn't clear enough or the question isn't *good enough*

Comment: `image` and `images[i]` refer to the *same image*.

Comment: And calling such functions is a waste of time. Just use `image.width`, seriously.

Comment: 1) You do not need to create helper functions for dereferencing properties from an object... only if you are actually performing logic that you feel should be pulled out into a separate function. 2) The reason your object in the array changes when the object you referenced from the array changes is because they are the same object. Array deferencing via index (ie: images[i]) creates a reference to the same object, not a copy of it. Here is a great answer on creating clones of objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/632676

Comment: In JavaScript, things are assigned by reference, not by value `image = images[i];` so change in `image` will also update `images[i]`;

Comment: @GPicazo Could you, please, explain what does *dereferencing properties from an object* mean?

Comment: Object's properties are passed as a reference, not as new ones. You could create a new object copy when assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @Robert - Dereferencing means to get the value (or data) stored in the memory location specified by a reference (also called pointers in other languages). In javascript, objects are passed/assigned by reference, meaning that an object variable does not really hold the value of the object, but instead, the reference to its location in memory. In your example, `image = images[i];` just created a new variable, image, that points to the same location as images[i]; therefore pointing to the same object. Object properties (ie: image.src) also point to the corresponding property in memory.

Comment: @GPicazo Thanks a lot. You explained it perfectly :)